# How to use global.json in Visual Studio 2022 to set SDK minor version when publishing project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, publish

According to Microsoft, using global.json is the correct way to publish with a specific minor version. However, i have searched the documentation but cannot find to include the file after creating it in Visual Studio 2022 when publishing the project. How can this be done?

Comment: I did, but there is nothing about incorporating the created global.json from Visual Studio when publishing the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

> The global.json file allows you to define which .NET SDK version is used when you run .NET CLI commands.

That is, when you *build* your app.

If you want to specify the *runtime* version instead of the SDK version, you should use [target frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

If you do want to specify the SDK version used to build the app, you could manually create a `global.json` file and add it to the current working directory as explained in the docs. The Publish wizard in Visual Studio won't do this for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the nuance now. But how do I specify the runtime minor version. More specifically i want to target machine to use .NET 6.0.8 instead of .NET 6.0.9 that's on my machine. Can the minor version be specified?

Comment: Publish a self-contained application that includes the selected runtime or disable roll-forwarding (not recommended) as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#framework-dependent-apps-roll-forward?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).